# Is undefined when try to reassign an property

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have this code :

```
this.applicationService.getApplications(id).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        forIn(GroupOrder,
            (value, key) => {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                let applicationGroup = {} as ApplicationGroupInterface;
                applicationGroup.count = 2;
                applicationGroup.applicationData = data[value];
                this.applications.push(applicationGroup);
            }
        });
        console.log(this.applications);
    });
```

I declared the `this.applications` on the beggining of component like `public applications`. But I get the error in console

> ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.applications is undefined`

the first console log works I have data in `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push an item into an array, first you need to initialize it. You can try by assigning an empty array

Set :

```
public applications : Array<any> = []
```